# Dúvida no relacionamento de tabelas MySQL Workbench

Tags: banco-de-dados, mysql

Olá, estou com um pequeno problema na criação duma base de dados.

O meu objectivo é criar uma tabela para marcar as presenças das pessoas nas aulas dos cursos em que estão inscritas.

A tabela 'presecas' deve conter o id da pessoa, do curso e da respectiva aula.
O meu objectivo é ao fazer a inserção dum tuplo na tabela de presenças em que só apareçam os IDs das aulas que pertencem aos cursos em que a pessoa está inscrita.

Já tentei várias ligações e na inserção, na tabela presenças, aparecem sempre IDs das aulas todas, preciso que só apareçam os IDs das aulas que pertencem aos cursos em que a pessoa está inscrita.

Esta imagem deve ajudar a perceber melhor o que quero fazer. Obrigado desde já ;)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Ligar a tabela `presenca` com `pessoas_has_curso` que possui duas chaves primárias? Assim na tabela `presenca` essas chaves também seriam primárias além de estrangeiras e teria uma chave de sequência primária para não duplicar valores.

Comment: E como vou buscar o ID da aula?

Comment: Chave estrangeira sem ser primary key rntre tabela aula e presenca.

Comment: ao fazer isso na inserção de dados na tabela presença aparecem IDs de aulas que não pertencem ao curso em que a pessoa está inscrita :S

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A minha sugestão, é que você *remova a tabela presença por completo*.
Você já tem uma tabela chamada `pessoa_has_curso` - eu sugiro que você crie uma tabela chamada `pessoa_has_aula`, com `FOREIGN KEYS` de `pessoa` e de `aula`.

Eu não tenho o [MySQL Workbench](https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/) para demonstrar, mas criei uma versão reduzida do seu DB.

Tabela `curso`:

```
CREATE TABLE curso (
curso_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
curso_nome VARCHAR(45),
PRIMARY KEY (curso_id)
);
```

Tabela `aula`:

```
CREATE TABLE aula (
aula_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
aula_nome VARCHAR(45),
curso_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (aula_id),
FOREIGN KEY (curso_id) REFERENCES curso (curso_id)
);
```

Tabela `pessoa`:

```
CREATE TABLE pessoa (
pessoa_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
pessoa_nome VARCHAR(45),
PRIMARY KEY (pessoa_id)
);
```

Tabela `pessoa_has_curso`:

```
CREATE TABLE pessoa_has_curso (
pessoa_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
curso_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY (pessoa_id) REFERENCES pessoa (pessoa_id),
FOREIGN KEY (curso_id) REFERENCES curso (curso_id)
);
```

E agora, a nova tabela, `pessoa_has_aula`:

```
CREATE TABLE pessoa_has_aula (
pessoa_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
aula_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY (pessoa_id) REFERENCES pessoa (pessoa_id),
FOREIGN KEY (aula_id) REFERENCES aula (aula_id)
);
```

Fiz inserções diversas de pessoas, cursos e aulas - mas não colocarei aqui por brevidade. A colocação de uma `pessoa` num `curso`, se dá assim:

```
INSERT INTO pessoa_has_curso (pessoa_id, curso_id) VALUES (3, 1);
```

Coloquei também `pessoa` em `aula`:

```
INSERT INTO pessoa_has_aula (pessoa_id, aula_id) VALUES (1, 6);
```

> Agora, fazendo as consultas corretas, acredito que você consiga todas
>   as informações que precisa.

Por exemplo, listar itens de `pessoa` que também estejam em `curso`:

```
SELECT pessoa.pessoa_nome AS Pessoas, curso.curso_nome AS Cursos
FROM pessoa_has_curso
INNER JOIN pessoa
ON pessoa_has_curso.pessoa_id = pessoa.pessoa_id
INNER JOIN curso
ON pessoa_has_curso.curso_id = curso.curso_id;
```

Resultado:

[image: Resultado Consulta de Pessoa e Curso]

Listando agora itens de `pessoa` que também estejam em `aula`:

```
SELECT pessoa.pessoa_nome AS Pessoas, aula.aula_nome as Aulas
FROM pessoa_has_aula
INNER JOIN pessoa
ON pessoa_has_aula.pessoa_id = pessoa.pessoa_id
INNER JOIN aula
ON pessoa_has_aula.aula_id = aula.aula_id;
```

Resultado:

[image: Resultado Consulta de Pessoa e Aula]

> Agora, pra responder sua pergunta, você disse que precisa dos `IDs` de
>   `aula` em que `pessoa` esteja participando.

Como agora nós temos uma tabela `pessoa_has_aula`, essa pesquisa se dá utilizando apenas ela, sem envolver a tabela `curso`:

```
SELECT aula_id AS AulaID
FROM pessoa_has_aula
INNER JOIN pessoa
ON pessoa_has_aula.pessoa_id = pessoa.pessoa_id
WHERE pessoa.pessoa_nome = 'Azurelle';
```

Resultado:

[image: Resultado Consulta de ID de aula e pessoa]

Dê uma olhada no [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b904bb/1).

Comment: Bacana a resposta e ainda tem um fiddle, +1 :D

Comment: Muito obrigado pela sua resposta longa e detalhada !

Comment: @Azurelle Se minha resposta for suficiente para resolver o seu problema, por favor clique na marca de verificação ao lado da resposta, para que ela fique marcada como "aceita" e saia da fila de perguntas por responder.